# download zip file using java?

Tags: java, download, zip, io

I am downloading zip file from web server using Java but somehow I am loosing about 2kb in each file. I don't know why since same code works fine with other formats, e.g, text, mp3 and extra.
any help is appreciated?
here is my code.

```
public void download_zip_file(String save_to) {
    try {
        URLConnection conn = this.url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("content-type", "binary/data");
        InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(save_to + "tmp.zip");

        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        int count;

        while ((count = in.read(b)) > 0) {
            out.write(b, 0, count);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have full control over server where the zip file is hosted? Does it work if you download the zip file using a normal webbrowser?

Comment: I don't have access to the web server but it works fine on the browser. I changed user agent and everything worked fine.

Comment: Drat, I would have suggested exactly that in an answer when you confirmed that it works fine in a normal browser :) The `setDoOutput(true)` by the way implicitly sets request method to POST. You normally don't want to use it for pure file downloads. Some servers would refuse the download when requested by POST instead of GET.

Comment: @BalusC - I have the same problem. My zip files get corrupted when I download using Java but the web browser works fine. What is the line of code that specifies the user agent that I need to add ?

Comment: @BalusC - there is NO content type binary/data. The code in the question is just wrong. I am not sure how this got approved.

Comment: @Jonik - can you look at the code in this question and correct the obvious mistake ?

Comment: @gansub: of course the code in question is wrong, otherwise the OP wouldn't have asked a question about the problem with the code. You'd better not fix the problem directly in question, as it would invalidate the concrete question. Instead just post an answer which concretely answers the problem in question. That's where Stack Overflow is all about.

Comment: @BalusC - what about the code fix that the OP did i.e. add the user agent part of the code ? Since he did not share it can you provide it ?

Answer (score 3):

It should be as below:

```
while ((count = in.read(b)) >= 0)
```

`in.read` can return `0`.

Comment: Wouldn't matter. If it returns 0, then there's simply nothing to write and thus also no need to write.

Comment: Yes, it matters. -1 should break the loop and nothing else.

Comment: I agree with zockman. 0 means there's nothing to write on this iteration, not that there is nothing left to write.

Answer (score 2):

Put an `out.flush()` just after the " `while ((count = in.read(b)) > 0) {...}`" section and before the `out.close()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the lines:

```
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("content-type", "binary/data");
```

Comment: did that, and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with downloading zip files from http once that turned out to be that my downloads included http headers in their beginning, but that made my files a bit larger not smaller, so you probably don't have this problem.

As a side note you might consider using [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) for download related apps - it's really great.

Answer (score 0):

A few years ago I remember running into a problem with an old version of Tomcat (5.5.25 for memory) that would cause largish downloads to be truncated.  We fixed this by upgrading to a 5.5.27.  I also recall the same problem was found and fixed in an early Tomcat 6.0 release.

If this rings any bells for you, take a look at the Tomcat change logs.

Answer (score 0):

Only zip files, huh?  Very odd.  Is it from any server, or just this one?  If you rename the file (change extension) do you get the same problem?  Which bytes are missing?  Are you sure it's the last 2K bytes and not some chunk from the middle/etc... ?

Comment: He mentioned 45 mins ago in a question comment that he already got it to work by changing the useragent.